# Why SIGTERM is able to kill sleep?

Tags: linux, process, signals

I did read that sleep can't handle any SIGNAL. So it seems to me that when I send `SIGTERM` to it, it should ignores it.

```
sleep 10000 &
26322
kill -s SIGTERM 26322
[1]+  Exited             sleep 1000
```

Why sleep is killed ? After all, it doesn't install any signal handlers.

Comment: Where did you read that? Notice that `sleep` is in `S` state by default and it means `interruptible sleep`. Maybe you mean `D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)`?

Answer (score 4):

A program that does not install a signal handler or explicitly ignores signals will take the default action if nothing else is mentioned.

The default action upon receiving the `TERM` signal is to exit the process.

---

For the `sleep` utility in particular, the only signal that is explicitly mentioned in the POSIX specification is the `ALRM` signal, which will cause the process to exit with a zero-exit status ("success"). `sleep` may also choose to ignore `ALRM` or to take the default action.  For all other signals, the default action will be taken.

See [the POSIX documentation for the `sleep` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/sleep.html).